# Woocommerce: Can I share category properties across products?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am looking for a way to share properties over different products which belong to the same category.

Let me explain:
I have a couple of products which share the same properties, but the color. To avoid entering data over and over, I'd like to add common properties to their category and show these properties as a part of the product-details.

Example: 
Let's say I have 'wireless headphones': They have different colors, sizes, etc... but they also share lots of identical properties. They're not product variations, but different products of the same kind.

Is there a way to add common properties of this category (e.g. 'stereo', 'wireless', 'frequency') to a single-product page?

Right now I am loading this data via Javascript from a .html template after the browser loaded the product. Works fine, but I guess there must be a better way, so I can handle these properties from within WooCommerce.

Any info/hint/pointer appreciated

Comment: You should find the answer in woocommerce support forum.

Answer (score 0):

This is what Attributes are used for.  Once you have your Attributes setup when you go into a product you can add the attribute that you are looking.  This video should help https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7PX8MWBOAeo

Comment: Thx for the link. The videos are really helpful. Unfortunately that doesn't solve my problem. What I want to create is category-templates and when I add a new product to the database, select from a list of categories (e.g. 'wireless headphones') which attaches all the properties found in the template to the product. (I tried the woocommerce support forum as well, but there was no reply)